# Parse iOS SDK v.1.7.4 FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix

Tags: parse-platform

Does anyone know how to handle UrlShemeSuffix with the latest Parse iOS SDK? I am only seeing this now.

```
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

This used to be available in a prior version of PFFacebookUtils but the v4 doesn't have it.

```
#ifdef PAID
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithUrlShemeSuffix:@"paid"];
#else
   [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithUrlShemeSuffix:@"free"];
#endif
```

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, answering my own question: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/115597585443651/